problem with connecting to the wifi
hey so i have a asus vivobook 14 and i did instatll Ubuntu OS 24.04.1 LTS, and at the beggining i fully install it and the wifi worked just fine.
after a day i turn on the PC and the wifi icon was shown but couldnt find any wifi`s arround (i am connected to the wifi with my other PC). after looking on the internet and saw to do sudo netplan --debug generate and moe the WARNING file to another directory and so i did (sudo mv /etc/netplan/*******.yaml /tmp/ and now i cant see the icon or the file i moved in the tmp directory how can i fix it?
